# htaccess rewrite subdirectory name to querystring param

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some specific needs for a certain directory of my website.  I need to change

```
/thisDirectory/subDirectory
```

to come through as

```
/thisDirectory?param=subDirectory
```

I'm having issues successfully creating an htaccess file that will do that.  I've tried SEVERAL different things, but I think this is the closest:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*)\??(.*)$ /directory/?page=$1&$2
```

I've been facing all kinds of 500 Server Errors, infinite redirect loops, etc etc.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m surprised that this does work at all in a per-directory context as you would have to strip the per-directory path prefix from the pattern:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically *removed* for the `RewriteRule` pattern matching and automatically *added* after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set.

In case of the document root directory that would be the leading `/` and the rule would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)\??(.*)$ /directory/?page=$1&$2
```

But besides that, `RewriteRule` can only check the URI path and not the query; you need [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to do that. So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/(.+)$ /directory/?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Here the `.+` instead of `.*` should avoid an infinite recursion as `.*` matches everything, even an empty string (that would be the case for the empty path segment after `/directory/`). And the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) is to automatically append the requested URI query to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

After much frustration... I think the issue was trying to do a rewrite to the same "directory" (although I thought the [L] would take care of it not looping... but that didn't seem to be the case).  I changed the name of the directory it was rewriting to and it seems to work...

```
RewriteBase /my/base/rewrite/
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ newDirectory/?page=$1 [L]
```